# Redirect to activity after clicking a button (Android)

Tags: android, button

I'm a newbie in android. How do I want to redirect to activity after clicking a button? I have a button which be a Floating action button. If user A clicks that button to redirect to activity A, if user B click that button to redirect to activity B, ...
Help me to solve it! Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

In xml add the following to the button

```
android:onClick:"onClick"
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a listener in your code as well:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setOnClickListener on the Floating Action Button, you can do that by implementing View.OnClickListener to your ActivityA.

Then simply start a new intent, add the below code to your ActivityA, inside the onClickListener of the Floating Action Button.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in onclick of button

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```